# Unable to use terraform with AWS IAM role with MFA configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My organisation uses a gateway account for which i have aws credentials.

We also have our personal account, in order to access our personal account users in gateway account assume IAM roles ( created in the personal account).

With such configuration i am trying to create terraform resource but somehow keep on getting error -> `Error: operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: xxxxxxx, api error AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:user/xx-xxxxxx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx2:role/xxxxxx`

Here is the provider configuration i am trying.

```
provider "aws" {
  alias      = "mad"
  profile    = "personal account"
  region     = "ap-south-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/personal account"
  }
}
```

Update :- the role uses mfa too.
Personal account has trust relationship which allows gatgeway account iam user to assume to role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::gateway-account-id:user/user"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The user `user/xx-xxxxxx` which you use to run the TF script which is going to assume role `role/xxxxxx` must have `sts:AssumeRole`.

You can add such permission to the user, by adding the following inline policy to it:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "sts:AssumeRole"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx2:role/xxxxxx"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also for MFA you need to use [token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#token) option in your provider configuration, or use any of the workarounds provided in TF [github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2420).

Comment: To clarify; my personal account has an IAM role which allows gateway account iam user to assume this role.

The policy is attached 

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::gatewayaccount:user/user"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @JatinMehrotra So how do you pass the MFA token to assume the role?

Comment: It works within console and aws cli, yes i do pass the mfa, if i am accesing console, there is a sperate screen, if i am using aws cli it always ask, cli and console does not have a problem

Comment: probably i am missing on the configuration for adding mfa config to provider :(

Comment: @JatinMehrotra TF does not ask for the token. You have to program around it yourself. There is a long standing [github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2420) on TF for that with possible solutions.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Also you can hardcode the token to the provider config using [token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#token).

Comment: Just to be clear, i think there are 2 issues 
1) even with correct permissions, terraform says user is not allowed to perform assume role
2) if `1` was solved then it won't ask for MFA right?

Or because there is no option for mfa that is why TF is showing me the permission error?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I think its the later. TF tries to assume the role without the MFA.

Comment: Cool, i will try to find custom solution for solving this problem.
will update accordingly.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Try adding [token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#token) option before you run the code first to make sure that this is the source of the access deny.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Did you find the custom solution?